# How to storage objects for communication without the database in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project where i do need to do a communication in 3 parts. Let me explain:

1.- The user fills a form, which is used to create a set of objects from the models. This objects are not saved in the database on this moment. All the objects are related between them.

2.- This objects must be saved in some way for an admin user to check the data and decide if proceed to save it, or if any element is invalid and reject the form.

3.- If the admin decide that the data is correct, select an option to send a .save() to add the data to the database.

At least that's the idea i have on how should work. I decided to create the objects before send it to the admin because it sounded easier to show that if i sended the request.POST and the request.FILES. My problem is that i don't know where could save the objects to show it to the admin when he connects(There are 2 types of users, Normal and Admin, the normal are the ones that fill the forms, the admins only check it, the two of them has their own views). So, does anyone how could i send the data and storage it until the admin connects? I'm open to any idea if this is not possible, the only thing that is necesary is the flow of: User fills the form, admin check it, data is saved or rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to `save()` them when the user submits the form at the start. Add a BooleanField to your model that says whether the row has been moderated and accepted. Then in your application, filter out all non-moderated rows, and on the admin side, filter out only rows that need moderation.

Comment: It was a bit harder than that for certain requirements, but at the end this was the right approach. Thanks!!